Running ansible script hosted in my GitHub repo
Are there any way on how to execute the ansible script that is hosted in my GitHub repo, without downloading or cloning it or basically saving it directly in the local machine, I just want to stay the script there in my GitHub account.
So basically, this is the sample snippet code in what I did try to make it work, I have tried running this one locally and it worked. However running it as a script hosted in GitHub does not work.
ansible-playbook https://raw.githubusercontent.com/username/reponame/main/ansible_config.yml
like for this one, whenever I paste the link in the browser it shows the the content of the .yml file.
However whenever I run the code, it says "Error playbook: could not be found".
I am currently using CentOS 7 machine. I would appreciate any help/ideas on how do I make this one work.

Please take note that in any case you are downloading the content, even if it is hold in memory only. Furthermore, you'll lose the advantage of having your workflow organized and structured in multiple files, as well using a central managed configuration file.
A minimal example playbook
---
- hosts: test
  become: false
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:

  - debug:

served via a Minimal web server using netcat or One-shot HTTP webserver to serve file contents using netcat
and called with
ansible-playbook --inventory example <(curl --silent http://localhost:8080)

will result into an output of
PLAY [test] ************

TASK [debug] ***********
ok: [one.example.com] =>
  msg: Hello world!

One may also test with
ansible-playbook --inventory example <(cat main.yml)

Then, one should think about, Is curl {something} | sudo bash - a reasonably safe installation method? However, for small and quick tests and tasks might it be a feasible approach.
Similar Q&A

Can ansible-playbook read from stdin instead of a file?

and further Links

How to use pipes and stdin with commands?
What does "< <(command args)" mean in the Shell?
What exactly is <() in Bash?
Pass tasklist through stdin

